# How to store Integer Hashset in SharedPreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, hashset

It says wrong 2nd argument type required set String.

```
Set<Integer> hs = pref.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<Integer>());
hs.add(String.valueOf(hs.size()+1));
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putStringSet("set", hs);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: Convert is to JSON using GSON. then save as String in SharedPreferences.

Comment: can you share example

Comment: `SharedPreference` doesn't support `Integer HashSet`. You need to manually do the conversion to and fro.

Comment: get**String**Set method is self-explaining, it returns a **String** set. You can't use it for **Integer** set

Comment: Check this library. You will Find Many Methods and regarding Shared Prefs. https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Answer (score 2):

You can do the conversion and store it in `SharedPreferences` like this,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<Integer> integerHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    integerHashSet.add(1);
    integerHashSet.add(2);

    //convert String HashSet to Integer HashSet
    Set<String> stringHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer i : integerHashSet) {
        stringHashSet.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    preferences.edit().putStringSet("set", stringHashSet).commit();
    Set<String> stringSet = preferences.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
    Set<Integer> integerSet = new HashSet<>();

    //Convert it back
    for (String str : stringSet) {
        integerSet.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }

    //now user integerSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Gson helps to convert custom object to string & string to custom object.
So you can convert set to string save to shared pref. And later get string from shared pref and convert to set.

To save

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<>();
String json = new Gson().toJson(mySet);
//Save json to shared pref
```

Then to retrieve

```
//get json from shared preference saved earlier
Set<Integer> mySet2 = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Set<Integer>>() {
            }.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

> It says wrong 2nd argument type required set String.

It's because you're incorrectly using the [getStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) with the following code:

```
Set<Integer> hs = pref.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<Integer>());
```

it should be like this:

```
Set<String> hs = pref.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
```

You should recognize the method signature which is clearly telling that the method is giving you a string set with `getStringSet`.